# Почему бот не хочет петь?

Tags: c#, бот, discord, discord-api

Делаю бота на C# c библиотекой DSharpPlus, делаю, чтобы бот воспроизводил музыку. Все сделал как по гайдам, бот заходит в голосовой, находит песню, но не проигрывает её.

Сам бот

```
private static DiscordClient? _client;
   private static CommandsNextExtension? _commands;

   public static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
       // configuration file config.json
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("config.json", true, true);
       var config = builder.Build();

       // client configuration
       DiscordConfiguration discordConfiguration = new DiscordConfiguration()
       {
           Intents = DiscordIntents.All,
           Token = config["token"],
           TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
           AutoReconnect = true
       };
       _client = new DiscordClient(discordConfiguration);
       _client.Ready += ClientReady;

       //command configuration
       CommandsNextConfiguration commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration()
       {
           StringPrefixes = new string[] { config["prefix"] },
           EnableMentionPrefix = true,
           EnableDms = true,
           EnableDefaultHelp = false
       };
       _commands = _client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);
       _commands.RegisterCommands<HolidayCommands>();


       //lavalink configuration
       ConnectionEndpoint endPoint = new ConnectionEndpoint
       {
           Hostname = "ssl.horizxon.studio",
           Port = 443,
           Secured = true
       };

       LavalinkConfiguration lavalinkConfig = new LavalinkConfiguration
       {
           Password = "horizxon.studio",
           RestEndpoint = endPoint,
           SocketEndpoint = endPoint,
       };
       var lavalink = _client.UseLavalink();

       await _client.ConnectAsync();
       //Task task = Task.Run((Action)TimeCheck);
       await lavalink.ConnectAsync(lavalinkConfig);
       await Task.Delay(-1);
   }

   private static Task ClientReady(DiscordClient sender, ReadyEventArgs args)
   {
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
```

Команда для проигрыша музыки:

```
internal class HolidayCommands : BaseCommandModule
    {


        [Command("play")]
        public async Task PlayMusicCommand(CommandContext context, [RemainingText] string songName)
        {
            // pre connect check
            if (context.Member.VoiceState == null)
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Зайди в войс, дубина!!");
                return;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(songName))
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Чё играть то?");
                return;
            }

            DiscordChannel? userVoiceChannel = context?.Member?.VoiceState.Channel;
            LavalinkExtension lavalinkInstance = context.Client.GetLavalink();


            if (!lavalinkInstance.ConnectedNodes.Any())
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Ошибка соединения");
                return;
            }

            if (userVoiceChannel.Type != DSharpPlus.ChannelType.Voice)
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Зайди в войс, дубина!!");
                return;
            }

            // connect to voice
            var node = lavalinkInstance.ConnectedNodes.Values.First();
            await node.ConnectAsync(userVoiceChannel);


            var connection = node.GetGuildConnection(context.Member.VoiceState.Guild);
            if (connection == null)
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Ошибка соединения с Lavalink");
                return;
            }

            var searchQuery = await node.Rest.GetTracksAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ");
            if (searchQuery.LoadResultType == LavalinkLoadResultType.NoMatches || searchQuery.LoadResultType == LavalinkLoadResultType.LoadFailed)
            {
                await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Не могу найти трек {songName}");
                return;
            }


            var track = searchQuery.Tracks.First();
            await connection.PlayAsync(track);

            string trackDescription = $"Название - {track.Title}\n" +
                                      $"Автор - {track.Author}\n" +
                                      $"Ccылка - {track.Uri}";

            DiscordEmbedBuilder nowPlayoingEmbed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
            {
                Color = DiscordColor.Yellow,
                Title = "Запустил",
                Description = trackDescription
            };

            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed: nowPlayoingEmbed);
        }
    }
```